# Excel Formula SUMIFS with substitute address match replace and concatenate

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, sumifs

I have my formula almost working. I'm stuck on the last step of adding the SUMIFS to the formula. The inner section works fine. I need help with taking the inner section results, which are for example E:E, and placing that into the sheet name reference. I know I need to use quotes " and concatenate &, but it throws an error and I haven't been able to troubleshoot it.

Here is what I want the formula to read as it gets evaluated...
=SUMIFS('17MY SQL'!E:E,'17MY SQL'!C:C,Compare!J1)

The E:E is dynamic and determined by this formula. This works, just cannot put it into the above formula without error.

=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B2,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B2,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""))

This is my current attempt (which results in an error).

=SUMIFS("'17MY SQL'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B5,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B5,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1","")),'17MY SQL'!$C:$C,Compare!I$1)

Comment: Two questions. 1) What error are you getting?  2) Can you share the data you are working with (or a scrubbed version)?

Comment: the error reads that it thinks this isn't a formula and recommends to comment it out with a ' before the = sign.

Comment: In the beginning with `=SUMIFS("'17MY ...` it should be `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'17MY ...` but I cannot figure out where to close off INDIRECT with a `)`.

Comment: use an excel beautifier to help see where to close.

Answer (score 0):

After about 25 more rounds of trial and error, I think I got it with indirect, though I don't understand why it's needed.

=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'17MY SQL'!"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B2,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(REPLACE(Compare!$B2,3,1,"*"),'17MY SQL'!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""))),'17MY SQL'!$C:$C,Compare!I$1)

Comment: ... because a text string like `"'17MY SQL'!E:E"` is not the same as a cell range like `'17MY SQL'!E:E`. To convert text-that-looks-like-a-cell-range to an actual  cell range, you need to wrap with INDIRECT.